# How can I debug my JavaScript code—in 2015?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

This question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988369/704972) in 2009 by suggesting [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

But the "Current stable: 2.0.7" "Firebug for Firefox" is "Compatible with: Firefox 30-37", and Firefox on OS X is at 40.0.

Is the answer to this question in late 2015 still Firebug?

**Update:** For the sake of desktop developers, if you're an experienced web developer who does not use (or no longer uses) Firebug, please suggest your favorite tool and, if you're feeling generous, point out to how: 1- one can set a breakpoint, 2- one can run and inspect a variable at that breakpoint.

Comment: Firebug is aptly named as often it causes bugs (very slow page response is typical) ... sure, they come out with a fix when that happens, but it can be a real pain in the butt. use the built in developer tools that come with every reputable browser, and internet explorer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're coming from a background of C++, Java, etc.., you will be pleasantly surprised that you need nothing more than a browser to debug Javascript. Firefox, for example, has a Debugger entry (under Tools \ Web Developer) that makes it possible to set breakpoints as simply as clicking in the margin. Indeed barebone Firefox is not just a runtime environment for running Javascript, it is also an IDE for Javascript. Notice that there is also Firefox Developer Edition, but the term "Developer" here refers to those developing Firefox, not the general developer. That edition is an early release of Firefox, but otherwise both are the same browser & IDE.

[image: Firefox-as-an-IDE]

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome dev tools and use Firefox Developer Edition. Both have very powerful capabilities and can do everything you need.

Comment: you don't need Firefox developer edition - all firefox have dev tools too, as does internet explorer and edge (I don't know about opera and safari, but I'd assume they do too) ... having said that about firefox developer edition, if you are a serious web developer, it is very handy to have a 12 week heads up on breaking changes in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Dev Tools is the best option, I guess.

Also, I recommend to use Chrome Canary instead of ordinary Chrome - in this case you'd be able to use latest features a bit earlier.
Enabling experimental features could be also useful sometimes.